# How do I join a classroom I just created using the classroom.create endpoint?

Tags: node.js, google-classroom

My code is:

```
createCourse(name, section){
    let self = this
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      request
        .post('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${self.accessToken}`)
        .type('json')
        .send({
          name: name,
          section: section,
          ownerId: 'me'
        })
        .end((err, res) =>{
          if(err) reject(err);
          resolve(new room(self, res.body))
        })
    })
  }
```

createCourse successfully creates the course, and i see an invite to teach on Google Classroom desktop. However I cant accept the invite to teach the course as `invitations.list` endpoint does not show me any available invitations. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to visit the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations).

To accept an invitation, you can try this [Method: invitations.accept](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations/accept).

> Accepts an invitation, removing it and adding the invited user to the
>   teachers or students (as appropriate) of the specified course. Only
>   the invited user may accept an invitation.